# Inter-process comunication between Windows service and web service

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-services, named-pipes

any help/feedback would be appreciated. I would like to develop a windows service in c# such that it would communicate through named pipes to a web service written in C#. Is this approach of inter-process possible? the reason behind using named pipes is performance.

Comment: When you say "a web service written in C#", is this hosted in IIS, and if not, how? If I understand you correctly, the fact that it is a "Web Service" is not relevant - what matters is what kind of process, running in what security context, hosts the code your Windows Service needs to communicate with via a Named Pipe.

Comment: @ChrisDickson Yes, the webservice is hosted in IIS. in fact, the windows service and web service are hosted on the same server (windows server). also, none of the services have security context. so my question is Named Pipes approached can be achieved in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally create a WCF Service and use the [netNamedPipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx) binding.

That link I provided contains a working example.

What you need to be aware of is that because of Windows 2008 Server hardening (includes windows 7), services are running in a different session Id (session 0) and would not have access to WCF services that are running in user mode.

Comment: thx for the sugestion however, the windows service must also connect through TCP to non windows environment so if i use WCF i wouldn't be able to use TCP protocol

Comment: Of course you can use TCP. You can host it on a different port for TCP.

Comment: if i understood correctly from the msdn specs if i use WCF, i can only use netNamedPipes and netTcp as protocols of communication. is this correct? if so, i would like to use the regular TCP protocol not the netTcp since this one is only use between windows machines.

Comment: @user945511 Then WCF is not for you. netTcp is propriety format of TCP as well as netNamedPipes. But if both client and server are WCF, it works very well.